# Sparql Alternative to inference - Modification of Query

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, 4store

As far as I know it is not possible to use sparql inference("?link") with 4store.

But somebody told me that it is possible to modify queries slightly if it is not possible to integrate inference.

How is it possible to avoid using inference by modifying the queries?

Comment: Have you seen http://4sreasoner.ecs.soton.ac.uk/ - Reasoning for 4store?

Comment: Duplicate question at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17263/sparql-alternative-to-inference-modification-of-query

Comment: I can't be bothered to create another *overflow account, but 4store doesn't do Property Paths, so 4sr is a better option.

Comment: 4sr does not do property paths either.

Comment: @msalvadores, but you don't need property paths to modify queries if you have inference enabled.